# How to publish a Class for an open source (Ex: NPM)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have created a Class using Javascript. I would like to publish it to any of the opensource. So that it will be a reference for me in future and people can use the functions within the class by creating objects(Ex: NPM). How can I do that? 
Please suggest me. (Other than Github)

Comment: Just use github or sourceforge, those are very common.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're interested in publishing your work as an NPM package, you might like to consider taking a look at chapter [11](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/creating-node-modules) and [12](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages) of the NPM 'Getting Started' docs.

Other than that, I'd say Github isn't a bad bet—a lot of the most popular libraries and packages (etc.) are housed in Github repos.